# How to speed Indexing process of Magento eCommerce website?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, cron

I have a Magento eCommerce website in which multiple cron jobs running that are updating the 30,000 products on here.  The indexing speed is horrible....I can't even update at the same rate as my supplier.   Inventory is being updated on 2 hour intervals when it should be 1 hour intervals.   Other cron jobs that should be run daily are being run weekly.  Are these things can be fix?  In addition I need to add about 3 more suppliers so I wanted know how to integrate it ?

I want this website to handle 100K+ products from many suppliers.   As it relates to adding additional suppliers with the same and different SKUs. Please suggest me possible ways to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At my shop the only way to get batch-operation inventory or catalog scripts to run quickly was to turn indexing off before the script started, and turn it back on and let the indexes rebuild after the updates were done.

This probably still works:

```
UPDATE index_process SET mode = 'manual';
```

Then run your update code, then:

```
UPDATE index_process SET mode = 'real_time';
```

Although you may want to be more selective about which indexes you disable/re-enable.